# API GitHub создание репозитория Python

Tags: python, api, github, requests

Отправляю запрос с помощью requests

```
headers = {"Authorization": "token %s" % token}
repos_url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos'
data =  {
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "description": "This is your first repository",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": False,
  "has_issues": True,
  "has_projects": True,
  "has_wiki": True
}
t = requests.get(repos_url,data=data,headers=headers)
print (t.json)
```

получаю ответ `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]`.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вы забыли метод вызвать: `print(t.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам у себя несколько ошибок.

1. print (t.json) - пропустил скобки ().
2. вместо get запроса необходимо отправлять post
3. data необходимо дампить в json  data=json.dumps(data)

Comment: можно: `json=data` передать. Для полноты можно добавить: `headers.update({'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'})`